# Is it possible to get audio data from the users audio device using NAudio to pass to Unity3D for visualization

Tags: unity-game-engine, naudio

What I am trying to do is grab the raw audio from the users audio output take that data and get an audio spectrum and output array similar to unity3d and pass that data to my visualizer.

So a couple things I need to know:

1. Can I grab the raw audio from the users device? What I have found so far is yes using waveinstream which by default gets audio data from all devices.
2. Can I grab the audio spectrum and output from that data similarly to Unity3D GetOutputData() and GetSpectrumData()? the NAudio demo provides similar functionality but not exactly what I want.

I am a newbie with coding naudio, whereas unity's API and extremely thorough documentation make it easier, naudio seems to have a couple tutorials and examples, nothing of what I need, and no API definitions. I will eventually figure it out but what I need to know is if what I'm attempting is possible, other than that any help is appreciated.

I provided my attempt at problem 1 which provides seemingly random data which I am trying to make sense of using a WaveFileReader but that crashes

---

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using NAudio.Wave;
using NAudio.CoreAudioApi;
using NAudio.Utils;

public class myNAudio : MonoBehaviour {

private WaveIn waveInStream;
private WaveFileReader reader;
private WaveStream readerStream;

void waveInStream_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e){
    //reader.Read(e.Buffer,0,e.BytesRecorded);
    //Debug.Log(e.Buffer);

    float tempDB = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < e.Buffer.Length; i++){
        //Debug.Log(i + " = " +e.Buffer[i]);
        tempDB += (float)e.Buffer[i]/255;
    }
    Debug.Log(e.Buffer.Length + ", " +tempDB);  
}

void OnApplicationQuit(){
    waveInStream.StopRecording();
    waveInStream.Dispose();
    waveInStream = null;
}

void OnDisable(){
    waveInStream.StopRecording();
    waveInStream.Dispose();
    waveInStream = null; 
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    waveInStream = new WaveIn();
    waveInStream.DeviceNumber = 0;

    waveInStream.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveInStream_DataAvailable);
    waveInStream.StartRecording();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
}
}
```